# Error: Cannot find module 'graphql/validation/rules/KnownArgumentNamesRule'

Tags: graphql, apollo

When I run the command `apollo client:codegen` the following error comes up :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'graphql/validation/rules/KnownArgumentNamesRule'
    Require stack:
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\@apo  
    llo\federation\dist\composition\validate\preNormalization\tagDirective.js    
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\@apo  
    llo\federation\dist\composition\validate\preNormalization\index.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\@apo  
    llo\federation\dist\composition\validate\index.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\@apo  
    llo\federation\dist\composition\composeAndValidate.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\@apo  
    llo\federation\dist\composition\index.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\@apo  
    llo\federation\dist\index.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\apol  
    lo-language-server\lib\providers\schema\file.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\apol  
    lo-language-server\lib\providers\schema\index.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\apol  
    lo-language-server\lib\project\base.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\apol  
    lo-language-server\lib\index.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\lib\commands\clie  
    nt\codegen.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\@ocl  
    if\config\lib\plugin.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\@ocl  
    if\config\lib\config.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\@ocl  
    if\config\lib\index.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\@ocl  
    if\command\lib\command.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\@ocl  
    if\command\lib\index.js
    - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\bin\run
    Code: MODULE_NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score 40):

Downgrading does not help. But installing graphql globally seem to solve the issue.

```
 npm install -g graphql
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does it work if you install it in the repo? some people like to avoid global installs

Answer (score 9):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling/issues/2415) with `apollo`. I followed the suggestion to [downgrade to `node` `v14.17.5`](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling/issues/2415#issuecomment-898595376), and everything worked.

Answer (score 8):

install both graphql and apalo globally

npm install -g graphql
npm install -g apollo

Answer (score 6):

You only have to install apollo(yarn add apollo) and fix the problem

Comment: For me for apollo/2.33.9 was to call sudo yarn global add apollo. (npm doesn't work) (MACOS)

Answer (score 5):

Very annoying issue, I installed graphql and apollo globally using node v 14. At the end this worked for me: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling/issues/2415#issuecomment-930173053

Now it works with node v 16 and w/o post install. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Just install appolo into your dev dependencies, e.g `yarn add -D apollo` and use it like `./node_modules/.bin/apollo client:codegen`

Answer (score 1):

I've tried on a windows PC instead of mac with following versions
apollo/2.34.0 win32-x64 node-v10.15.3

That worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).