# How to uninstall latest node & downgrade to old version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, apollo

Error: Cannot find module 'graphql/validation/rules/KnownArgumentNamesRule' Require stack: - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules@apo
llo\federation\dist\composition\validate\preNormalization\tagDirective.js

- C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules@apo
  llo\federation\dist\composition\validate\preNormalization\index.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules@apo
  llo\federation\dist\composition\validate\index.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules@apo
  llo\federation\dist\composition\composeAndValidate.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules@apo
  llo\federation\dist\composition\index.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules@apo
  llo\federation\dist\index.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\apol
  lo-language-server\lib\providers\schema\file.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\apol
  lo-language-server\lib\providers\schema\index.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\apol
  lo-language-server\lib\project\base.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\apol
  lo-language-server\lib\index.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\lib\commands\clie
  nt\codegen.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules@ocl
  if\config\lib\plugin.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules@ocl
  if\config\lib\config.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules@ocl
  if\config\lib\index.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules@ocl
  if\command\lib\command.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\node_modules@ocl
  if\command\lib\index.js - C:\Users\Minseo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apollo\bin\run Code: MODULE_NOT_FOUND

I face this issue while downloading schema in latest version of node, so i want to downgrade it to previous version.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Cannot find module 'graphql/validation/rules/KnownArgumentNamesRule'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68855003/error-cannot-find-module-graphql-validation-rules-knownargumentnamesrule)

Answer (score 0):

**Open Terminal & run these command on macbook**

1. cd /usr/local/include
2. sudo rm -R node
3. cd ../lib
4. sudo rm -R node_modules
5. cd ../bin
6. sudo rm -R node

**After that check node version if it's uninstall compeletely enter **
node -v

**Result**
"-bash: node: command not found"

Answer (score 0):

You can use NVM(Node Version Manager).

**First Step **

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

**Second Step**

Install Specific Version Using NVM

```
nvm install <version>
```

if you are getting any error of nvm use below code

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

then again follow the second step

**Third step**

use this below command

```
nvm use <version>
```

then check the version

```
node -v
```